# Transform this React snippet to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

Hi I am labbing with this code snippet and want to use it in Typescript but it complains about the useRef type and many more. Most importantly: it doesn't allow the next.focus();. It just says "Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)"

Is it "not ok" in typescript to use the .focus() or do it want me to use onFocus or something?

The link to the Sandbox: https://codepen.io/vitalyq/pen/GRNXmQY?editors=0011

Here's the code in just React:

```
function useFocusNext() {
  const controls = useRef([]);

  const handler = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {

      const index = controls.current.indexOf(event.target);
      const next = controls.current[index + 1];
      next && next.focus();

      // IE 9, 10
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return useCallback((element) => {
    if (element && !controls.current.includes(element)) {
      controls.current.push(element);
      element.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
    }
  }, []);
};

function Form() {
  const focusNextRef = useFocusNext();
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const toggleMore = () => setShowMore((last) => !last);

  return (
    <>
      <input ref={focusNextRef} placeholder="Field 1" />
      {showMore && <>
        <input ref={focusNextRef} placeholder="Added Field" />
      </>}
      <input ref={focusNextRef} placeholder="Field 2" />
      <button ref={focusNextRef}>Submit</button>
      <button onClick={toggleMore}>Toggle More Fields</button>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And here's my code trying to transform it

```
  const useFocusNext = () => {
    const controls: MutableRefObject<never[]> = useRef([]);

    const handler = (event: {
      keyCode: number;
      target: any;
      preventDefault: () => void;
    }) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        if(event && event.target) {
          const index: number = controls.current.indexOf(event.target as never);
          const next = controls.current[index + 1];
          if (next) {
            next.focus();
          }
        }

        // IE 9, 10
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };

    return useCallback((element) => {
      if (element && !controls.current.includes(element as never)) {
        controls.current.push(element as never);
        element.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
      }
    }, []);
  };
```

Comment: `never` is what you want to avoid, not add it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have an array of `HTMLElement` so:

```
useRef<HTMLElement[]>([])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `never` issue is that you're telling TypeScript that the elements in `controls.current` will never exist; that's what [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never) says. Your controls will be `HTMLElement` instances, so use `HTMLElement[]` instead.

But the next problem is that you need a type on the `element` parameter of the function you return from `useFocusNext`, so TypeScript knows what values you're allowed to call it with. Also, in your `handler` function, `event` implicitly has the type `any` (I recommend enabling `noImplicitAny` so TypeScript flags this up); you'll want to say specifically it's a `KeyboardEvent`. That would also have allowed your IDE to flag up that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code; use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

See the indicated portions below:

```typescript
function useFocusNext() {
    const controls = useRef<HTMLElement[]>([]);
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    const handler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            const index = controls.current.indexOf(event.target as HTMLElement);
            // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            const next = controls.current[index + 1];
            if (next) {
                next.focus();
            }

            // IE 9, 10
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    return useCallback((element: HTMLElement | null) => {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (element && !controls.current.includes(element)) {
            controls.current.push(element);
            element.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
        }
    }, []);
}
```

(No changes to `Form` were required.)

---

That said, I would avoid having code adding event listeners it never removes, and adding event listeners to each and every element in the form. Instead, I'd use a single event listener on a containing element, something along these lines:

```typescript
function useFocusNext() {
    const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const form = formRef.current;
        if (!form) {
            return;
        }
        // assert(form);
        const handler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const elements = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll(".handle-next")) as HTMLElement[];
                const index = elements.indexOf(event.target as HTMLElement);
                const next = elements[index + 1];
                if (next) {
                    next.focus();
                }
            }
        };
        form.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
        return () => {
            form.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
        }
    }, []);

    return formRef;
}

function Form(props: any) {
    const formRef = useFocusNext();
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
    const toggleMore = () => setShowMore((last) => !last);

    return (
        <form {...props} ref={formRef}>
            <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Field 1" />
            {showMore && (
                <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Added Field" />
            )}
            <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Field 2" />
            <button className="handle-next">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={toggleMore}>Toggle More Fields</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

That adds a `form` element around the form and handles events on it; the fields you want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> handled on are indicated with a class. (Or it could be a `data-*` attribute or something.) And the event handler is cleaned up when the component instance using it is unmounted. Notice that any `button` element that you don't want to submit the form needs to be `type="button"` since the default for `button`'s `type` is `"submit"`. Alternatively, use a non-`form` element, although it's good for semantics to use one.

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function useFocusNext() {
    const formRef = useRef/*<HTMLFormElement>*/(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const form = formRef.current;
        if (!form) {
            return;
        }
        // assert(form);
        const handler = (event/*: KeyboardEvent*/) => {
            if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const elements = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll(".handle-next"))/* as HTMLElement[]*/;
                const index = elements.indexOf(event.target/* as HTMLElement*/);
                const next = elements[index + 1];
                if (next) {
                    next.focus();
                }
            }
        };
        form.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
        return () => {
            form.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
        }
    }, []);

    return formRef;
}

function Form(props: any) {
    const formRef = useFocusNext();
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
    const toggleMore = () => setShowMore((last) => !last);

    return (
        <form {...props} ref={formRef}>
            <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Field 1" />
            {showMore && (
                <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Added Field" />
            )}
            <input className="handle-next" placeholder="Field 2" />
            <button className="handle-next">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={toggleMore}>Toggle More Fields</button>
        </form>
    );
}

const Example = () => {
    return <Form/>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That code has to have a couple of type assertions to tell TypeScript that we know we're dealing with `HTMLElement` instances, not just `Element` instances, since `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeListOf<Element>` and `event.target`'s type is just `EventTarget`. If you find yourself having to query HTML elements often, you'd probably be better off with a utility function with a more specific return type, and maybe even a subtype of `KeyboardEvent` that refines the type of `target`.

Comment: Ok thanks for an well explained solution. Unfortunately doesn't the "Toggle More Fields"-button show more Fields...? :(

Comment: @kt74ys - That's because the default `type` of a `button` element is `submit`, not `button`. I've added `type="button"` to that button, and added a note about it to the answer.